# Proof $P(\limsup X_n=5)=1$

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, uniform-distribution, borel-cantelli-lemmas

This is Problem 3.6.11 from Rosenthal's 'First look at Rigorous Probability Theory'. I think I did it correctly, but suggestions and comments are very welcome.

For $X_n \sim Uniform\left[\frac1n\right], \ n \in \mathrm N$ find $P(\lim\sup X_n = 5)$.

By definition of $\limsup, \liminf$ and DeMorgan's Laws, 
$$
P(\limsup_n X_n) = 1-P((\lim\sup_n X_n)^c) = 1 -  P(\lim\inf_n X^c_n)
$$
where $X^c_n$ is event 'not 5' in $n^{th}$ rv. From the definition of $\liminf$ and subadditivity
$$
1 - P(\liminf_n X^c_n) = 1 - P\left(\bigcup_{n=4}^{\infty} \bigcap_{k=n}^\infty  X^c_k\right) \geq 1 -  \sum_{n=4}^{\infty}P\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty X^c_k\right) 
$$
By independence, and definition of countable/discrete Uniform rv, $P(X^c_k) = \frac{k-1}k$ and the fact that the expression only makes sense for $n \geq 5$:
$$
P\left(\bigcap_{k=4}^{\infty} X^c_k\right) = \lim_{M \to \infty} \prod_{k=4}^M(1-P(X_k)) = \lim_{M \to \infty}\frac45 \cdot\frac56\cdots\frac{M-1}M = \lim_{M \to \infty}\frac4M= 0
$$
Therefore, every term in the infinite sum converges to $0$, so the sum if $0$
$$
\sum_{n=4}^{\infty}P\left(\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty X^c_k\right)  = 0
$$
Putting it all together,
$$
P(\limsup_n X_n) = 1-0 = 1
$$
So the event 'get 5' happens infinitely often w.p. $1$.

Comment: What is Uniform[1/n]?

Comment: Countable Uniform distribution with parameter $\frac{1}{n}$, i.e. $X_n \sim Uniform(\frac{1}{n})$

Comment: a countable uniform distribution does not exist.

Comment: He probably meant $Uniform(\frac{1}{n})$ is a uniform distribution on $\{1,...,n\}$, but it should be specified. What's more, your inequality $1 - \mathbb P(\bigcup \bigcap X_k^c) \ge 1 - \mathbb P(\bigcap X_k^c)$ isn't true, since $\mathbb P(\bigcup \bigcap X_k^c) \ge \mathbb P(\bigcap X_k^c)$. Do you have other assumption, for example $X_n$ are independent? Then borel cantelli should do

Comment: $n \in N$, its specified

Comment: Yes they are independent. I see your point about the union. I'll check it again

Comment: @DominikKutek: I fixed the subadditivity argument, thanks. Is it OK now?

Comment: I wouldn't use the same name for event and variables. Only small correction: $\prod_{k=n}^M \mathbb P(X_k^c) = \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot ... \cdot \frac{M-1}{M} = \frac{n-1}{M} \to 0$, since you're starting multiplying from $k=n$, not from $k=4$. Another approach could be $\mathbb P(X_k=5) = \frac{1}{k}$ (for $k \ge 5$), so $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \mathbb P(X_k=5) = \sum_{k=5}^\infty \frac{1}{k} = \infty$, and since events are independent, then by Borel Cantelli we get $\mathbb P(\limsup \{ X_k =5 \}) = 1$.

Comment: @DominikKutek: thanks, I fixed it to start at $4$, since obviously for lesser values the expression doesn't make sense. Your proof is much better, but I decided to go the long way.

Comment: Saying $X_n \sim Uniform[1/n]$, $n \in N$ is not clear and does not specify anything.  The Dominik Kutek suggestion gives a meaningful **guess** at a formulation, I would not have guessed that interpretation from its description and I do not think most people would.  This cannot be described as "Countable uniform distribution with parameter $1/n$."

Comment: @Michael: OK, the support of the distribution is $1, 2, \ldots n$, n arbitrarily large, probability of each $P(X=n)=\frac{1}{n}$. What would you call this disrtibution?

Comment: In my question I meant of course a sequence of random variables $X_n$

Comment: I think you mean $P[X_n = i] = 1/n$ for $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  You can say that $X_n$ is  uniformly distributed over the integers $\{1, ..., n\}$.

Comment: OK, but if $n$ grows arbitrarily large, this coincides with $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: I don't know what is meant by "coincides with $\mathbb{N}$."   That should not confuse the fact that for each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$, the random variable $X_n$ is assumed to be uniformly distributed over the integers $\{1, ..., n\}$.  The notation $X_n \sim Uniform[1/n]$ I would have interpreted to mean that $X_n$ has a continuous CDF and is uniformly distributed over the real interval $[0,1/n]$.

Comment: @Michael: OK, so in your opinion what would be the correct formulation for a rv with a uniform distribution over integers $1 \ldots n$ s.t. $n \to \infty$?

Comment: I do not see where the number "5" comes from. So, I'm not sure this interpretation $X_n$ uniform over $\{1, ..., n\}$ is correct. Are the $X_n$ values independent? If so it seems to me that $\{X_n=n\}$ occurs infinitely often and so the $\limsup_n X_n=\infty$ with prob 1.

Comment: @Michael, it is yet another flaw in formulation. Alex probably meant $\limsup$ of events $\{X_n = 5\}$ and not the $\limsup$ of sequence. Yet it is only another guess, but I guessed so due to his use of $\limsup,\liminf$ as an operation with intersections and sums of sets. But you're definitelly right, that (given independence, which Alex mentioned only in the commencts) $\limsup_n X_n = \infty$ almost surely, but $\limsup_n \{ X_n = 5\}$ is of measure $1$, too (what probably was of Alex's interest)

Comment: @DominikKutek: if you saw the title it said $P(\limsup X_n =5)$, so of course it's the event $X_n=5$. I guess it woud be better if I changed the notation to $Y_n \equiv X_n=5$ and use it instead.